# Change Dylib Version

Tags: macos, dylib, pdfnet

or one of my programms I use a Dynamic link library. Called **PDFNet**

I was using version **6.5.0** now I would like to change to **6.5.1**

I downloaded the new version and let this command run with the path to the libary:

```
otool -L /Downloads/PDFNetCMac/Lib/libPDFNetC.dylib.6.5.1 
/Downloads/PDFNetCMac/Lib/libPDFNetC.dylib.6.5.1:
 @rpath/libPDFNetC.dylib (compatibility version 6.5.0, current version 6.5.0)
```

So there I see current version **6.5.0** How can I change to **6.5.1**? Thanks

Comment: perhaps check out install_name_tool libtool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded the latest OSX nightly (stable) build. There should be a libPDFNetC.dylib file that is a symlink to the latest libPDFNetC.dylib.x.y.z. Which last night was libPDFNetC.dylib.6.5.1

If you do `ls -l` you should see that libPDFNetC.dylib is pointing to the 6.5.1 library.

I'm not sure why otool lists `@rpath/libPDFNetC.dylib (compatibility version 6.5.0, current version 6.5.0)` instead of 6.5.1.